# How to use python pydub to convert mp3 data(bytes) to wav data(bytes) without storing data to file?

Tags: pydub

How to use python pydub to convert mp3 data(bytes) to wav data(bytes) without storing data to file?

```
    seg=AudioSegment(data=mp3_data)
    seg.set_frame_rate(16000)
    seg.set_channels(1)
    # no function named set_format
    # seg.set_foramt("wav")
    return seg.raw_data
```

Updated:
Oh, I see. BytesIO can be used like this:

```
from io import BytesIO
seg=AudioSegment.from_mp3(BytesIO(mp3_data))
seg=seg.set_frame_rate(vosk_sample_rate)
seg=seg.set_channels(1)
wavIO=BytesIO()
seg.export(wavIO, format="wav")
return wavIO.getvalue()
```

Comment: if you resolved your problem then you can put it as answer.

Comment: Worked for me like a charm. Thanks for updating your initial question !