# How to convert a audio-segment file into bytes type?

Tags: python, audio, byte, speech-recognition, pydub

I want to make a speech recognition from a wav.
To do that, I have a wav that I split into multiple chunks, export them, and then use the SpeechRecognition library.

```
from pydub import AudioSegment
import speech_recognition as sr

r = sr.Recognizer()
for i in range(5):
    audio = AudioSegment.from_wav("some_wav.wav")
    audio_chunk=audio[int(i*1000):int(i*3000)]
    audio_chunk.export('test.wav', format='wav')
    detection = sr.AudioFile('test.wav')

    with detection as source:
        audio = r.record(source)

    word = r.recognize_google(audio, language = 'ro-RO')
```

The problem is that this is not very optimal. I want to get rid of the export wav part. I want to transform the audio_chunk into bytes and then use it in the speechRecognition.AudioFile() with in-memory bytes.

Is there a way to convert the audio-segment type into bytes?

Comment: This helped me to convert an AudioSegment to bytes https://stackoverflow.com/q/67631465/17524305

Answer (score 1):

1 year late but try using a buffer to keep the audio bytes in memory.

```
from pydub import AudioSegment
import speech_recognition as sr
import io

r = sr.Recognizer()
for i in range(5):
    audio = AudioSegment.from_wav("some_wav.wav")
    audio_chunk = audio[int(i*1000):int(i*3000)]
    
    buffer = io.BytesIO()
    audio_chunk.export(buffer, format="wav")
    detection = sr.AudioFile(buffer)

    with detection as source:
        audio = r.record(source)

    word = r.recognize_google(audio, language='ro-RO')
```

Comment: Code alone is insufficient as an answer. Please add explanations how your answer solves the problem.

Comment: I had an issue passing bytes directly into the sr.Recognizer() module. This solution worked great for me. Thank yoy!