# How do I convert a PyDub AudioSegment object into a SpeechRecognition AudioData object?

Tags: python, audio, speech-recognition, pydub

I'm trying to break an audio file into small subsections, and then perform speech recognition on each small subsection. To do this, I am splitting the file up using PyDub, and hoping to input it into the SpeechRecognition library. However, I want to do this without needing to save each small audio chunk to disk, and then re-read it. Hence, I want to do an in-memory conversion from the PyDub.AudioSegment object to a speech_recognition.AudioData object.

Is there any way to do this?

(I'm looking for a similar end result to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73317320/how-to-convert-a-audio-segment-file-into-bytes-type))

I've already got the original audio split into segments, and stored in a list.

Answer (score 0):

```
audio = AudioSegment.from_file("audio.wav", format="wav")
extracted = audio[start:end]
buffer = io.BytesIO()
extracted.export(buffer, format="wav")
buffer.seek(0)
```

Now use buffer as input for the Speech Recognition

Comment: AudioSegment from pydub